# Getting Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE). when using memcache in kohana

Tags: php, memcached, kohana

i'm getting this error when i try to use memcache using kohana. all i did was changed the hostname in the configuration file and used `$cache = Cache::instance('memcache');`.

i can telnet my memcached servers so probably the problem is not there.

any help?

Comment: Whats in your Apache (you are using Apache, right?) log?

Comment: yeah. found the answer in my apache log. it seems the i have a lengthy token name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error described is a Google Chrome error. This suggests that Kohana is not responding with anything, most likely because the error/exception handling is being suppressed. Check that PHP `error_reporting` is on (`E_ALL` is a good value).

If there still is no output, it could be that PHP is segfaulting during execution. If so you should be able to find out what is wrong in your web server logs if not the system log.

My best guess is that php-memcache and/or the memcache library is not compiled correctly or has been corrupted.

Answer (score 5):

When using a PHP framework like FuelPHP
https://fuelphp.com/forums/topics/view/4256#11344

**Problem**

- In Google Chrome "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server
  closed the connection without sending any data."
- No PHP errors, due to Apache dying before anything is sent back to the browser
- In Apache logs, this not helpful message "Error [notice] child pid 19647 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)"

**Solution**
Double check there is an opening php tag (duh!), or check for other silly, rookie syntax mistakes.

Comment: actually in my case it was the length (too long) of the memcache key.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduced this problem in local as my local and server have different environment. This happened after setting the PDO

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $user, $pass, 
  array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
```

However after run an update for `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`. Problem fixed. So this could be one of the things you can check if you have run out of idea where's the problem coming from.