# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): in Google Chrome

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, memcached

I have a user saying that he is getting the following message when he visits any of our sites on our web server:

Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE):

Done some googling and alot point to plugins, so we had a go with those first, but the problem still occured. Cleared cache which stopped the problem for a while, but it comes back. Sites are fine in all other browsers.

Found this which says something about a token, but don't know what they are talking about:

[Getting Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE). when using memcache in kohana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329462/getting-error-324-neterr-empty-response-when-using-memcache-in-kohana)

Help Please?

Comment: I suspect [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329462/getting-error-324-neterr-empty-response-when-using-memcache-in-kohana/6440475#6440475) is the same - the browser isn't seeing any response from the server because error logging is silent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107576

adding -disable-ssl-false-start to the chrome start up seems to be a temp work around to the issue for this site

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case but with SSL only on an older version of lighttpd.

Since it's only Chrome causing the problem it feels like it might be due to Chrome's TLS False Start feature that was rolled out in early 2011 I believe.

In my case the problem was solved by upgrading lighttpd (to 1.4.28 for those interested).

More details about the False Start feature here:
http://www.z-car.com/blog/2010/12/10/google-chromes-new-false-start-feature